# Submit form with different variable php

Tags: php, form-submit

I have a table in mysql with some variable:

`data price 1 price 2 price 3 price 4`

I have a form in a html page with the same field (data;price 1;price 2;price 3;price 4) that client must select (they are option value form)

I use this php formula to calculate an estimate

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(price1)FROM preventivo Where data>='$_POST[arrivo]' and data <'$_POST[partenza]'"; 
$dave= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dave)){ 
foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){ 
print "$cvalue\t";}
}
```

If I repeat this formula for all price (price 1,price2, price3 and price 4) the form doesn't work

Finally I need a fomula that takes into account the possible value of all 4 prices and do the sum among them their

Comment: If your form's elements contains a space `price 1` etc. then that is one reason for it to fail. Use undercores `price_1`. Plus, if your table's columns also contain spaces, then either wrap them in backticks, or use underscores for those also. It's hard to say for sure, without seeing the actual codes used.

Comment: no in the table is price1...I fall to write

Comment: Just checking. Some actually use what they've posted in their questions for actuals.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign aliases to your sums:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(price1) AS sum1, SUM(price2) AS sum2, SUM(price3) AS sum3, SUM(price4) AS sum4
          FROM preventivo Where data>='$_POST[arrivo]' and data <'$_POST[partenza]'";
```

Then you can access them as `$row['sum1']`, `$row['sum2']` and so on.

P.S. You should convert from the deprecated mysql_XXX functions to PDO or mysqli, and use parametrized queries.

Comment: sorry so I need to write
$query = "as you said";

$dave= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dave)){
    foreach($row['sum1'] as $cname => $cvalue){
       print "$cvalue\t";
    }
 
}
($row['sum12'] as $cname => $cvalue){
       print "$cvalue\t";
    }
 
}

etc??